# CSS SVG-file remove padding when used as background-image

Tags: html, css, image, svg, padding

I'm trying to take a logo that I have and introduce it inside an element on the page as a background-image for that element. However the image gets "padded" and the logo comes out extremely small. Are there any good solutions for this problem?

[image: Picture of how it looks atm.]

[image: Picture of the div's dimensions.]

[And the source SVG.](http://svgur.com/s/78t)

Here is the current css:

```
/* Searchbardiv */
.searchbarContainer{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
/* logoDiv */
.logo {
    background-image: url("/static/images/logo/LiquidMarket.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="searchbarContainer">
  <div class="logoAndLinks">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="buttonNavigation">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside($event)" (click)="dropfunction('myDropdown0')" id="dropbtn0" class="dropbtn">Home</button>
        <div id="myDropdown0" class="dropdown-content">
            <a routerLink="/"> Index </a>
            <a routerLink="/profile">Profile</a>
            <div *ngIf="currentUser">
              <a routerLink="/login">Logout</a>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!currentUser">
              <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
              <a routerLink="/register">Register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside($event)" (click)="dropfunction('myDropdown1')" id="dropbtn1" class="dropbtn">My invoices</button>
        <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
            <a routerLink="/invoices"> Invoices </a>
            <a routerLink="/registerinvoice">Register invoice</a>
            <a routerLink="/orders">Orders</a>
            <a routerLink="/transactions">Transactions</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside($event)" (click)="dropfunction('myDropdown2')" id="dropbtn2" class="dropbtn">Marketplace</button>
        <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
          <a routerLink="/ordering">Place order</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solved by opening the image in Gedit and adjusting viewbox from: `viewBox="0 0 800 600"` to `viewBox="200 200 400 200"`

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a div with the class 'logo' instead of using an image and styling that? Using it as a background image will not display it how you intend.

Comment: Your svg isn't a true svg. You're using a png image inside of your svg tag. The best solution would be is to save the png separately and crop it so that you'll remove the padding use that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the very first line of your SVG you can read:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 225.14 168.86">
```

The `viewBox` attribute says that what is to be viewed is in those 225x168 pixels. You could even have some other graphic outside that limit and you won't ever see it.

To accomplish what you seek you have to edit the SVG with your favourite editor to enclose sharply your logo and to have the ratio you want.

I recommend you to edit your SVG instead of using some clipping based method.

### Update

I further analized your SVG file and I discovered it's a raster image (linke a jpg or a png) encapsulated in a svg, so there's no real vector graphic in there and the above solution does not apply.

Extract the raster from the svg and use it and edit it like any other image you would.

Comment: I see, I'm going to try to implement this right away.

Comment: I've been searching without finding a way to edit the SVG, can you do that in css, do you have some example code for that? Or is that done in an image editor? I opened it in Inkscape without being able to find out how it's done, do you have any pointers for how i go about editing the viewbox?

Comment: With Inkscape you can do it in document properties > Page (tab) > Customize dimensions.
If you expand the Customize section with the [+] there's the useful button "Resize page to drawing". Alternatively, with a text editor, you can edit those values by hand but it's a non-trivial task.